# go http запрос с куками

Tags: http, golang, cookie

Помогите примером кода пожалуйста, задача в следующем (на стороне клиента): 
1. Отправляю http запрос 
2. из ответа извлечь и сохранить куки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду на стороне сервера, то вот простейший пример. Обработка ошибок опущена для краткости.

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("cookies:")
    for i, c := range r.Cookies() {
        log.Printf("%d: %s", i, c)
    }
})

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

Пример вывода:

```
2019/08/02 21:50:54 cookies:
2019/08/02 21:50:54 0: foo=bar
2019/08/02 21:50:54 1: baz=quux
```

Со стороны клиента:

```golang
resp, _ := http.Get("https://google.com")
defer resp.Body.Close()

log.Printf("cookies:")
for i, c := range resp.Cookies() {
    log.Printf("%d: %s", i, c)
}
```

Сокращённый пример вывода:

```
2019/08/02 22:06:27 0: 1P_JAR=2019-08-02-19; Path=/; (…)
2019/08/02 22:06:27 1: NID=188=QhmxsFZpj8sbT1qZbcdPx (…)
```

Comment: Прошу прощения за эту путаницу, подразумевался запрос со стороны клиента.

Comment: @анонимныйвопрошатель См. правку.